# How to simulate SHIFT + Mouse key press in java

Tags: java, swing

I want to move the mouse pointer to a particular location and perform SHIFT + right mouse button click. I am able to move the mouse to a location but not able to simulate mouse click.

```
Robot r = new Robot();
r.mouseMove(x1,y1);
```

What should i do to simulate the expected mouse click?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you will need just a little extra information for Robot to complete successfully, try

```
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
r.mousePress(KeyEvent.BUTTON3_MASK);
r.mouseRelease(KeyEvent.BUTTON3_MASK);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
```

Comment: @DarkKnight Sorry, my bad, copied other peoples code and didn't check it :P - I've tested and updated the example

Answer (score 1):

this should do the trick:

```
r.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON3_MASK);
r.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON3_MASK);
```

Important here is not to forget to press and release it, since those are 2 diffrent events.

Comment: Is it equivalent to MouseEvent.BUTTON1_MASK | MouseEvent.SHIFT_MASK ?

Comment: MouseEvent extends InputEvent, so it might work aswell, but InputEvent works 100%. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html

Comment: @Ossie7 Could you please link to Java 7 APIs in the future, it helps highlight possible deprecated APIs to users, among other things ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer, my bad, I just picked the first one of google :$ - fixed it now

Comment: @Ossie7 Yeah, I have the same habit, but it can earn you a down vote (I'm not that mean ;))

Answer (score 1):

Pressing a key with the `robot` `class` is simple:

```
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT); //hold down shift
r.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON3_MASK); //perform a right click
r.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON3_MASK); //release right click
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT); //release shift
```

`InputEvent` and `KeyEvent` are in `java.awt.event`.