# Simulate Keys presses with java application

Tags: java, key

Can I simulate a key presses with a java application to make system hear them?

Comment: Are you looking for a way to do this with an application you're writing?  If that's the case, this question will likely be migrated to StackOverflow shortly.

Comment: no, i'd like to print them out of java application... is it possible?

Comment: I honestly don't know what you're asking.  Can you elaborate more?

Comment: I need that my java application robot simulate the CTRL + C of the keyboard when i press a HotKeys combination...

Comment: Does it have to be java?  Auto Hotkey and Event Ghost might be better choices.

Comment: You can use `java.awt.Robot` to inject key events into the system. These keys will be avaliable to what ever window/component has focus.  Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14595483/using-java-to-send-key-combinations/14595522#14595522) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12188076/how-to-simulate-shift-mouse-key-press-in-java/12188180#12188180) for some examples

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate keyboard presses with Java (using the [AWT Robot](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class) but you can listen to key events only if you have a GUI in focus (or if you interact with native C code, but that would be pretty complicated)

For global hotkeys, it would be very easy to do it using [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) instead of Java, as  MBraedley suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate keyboard presses with java by implementing KeyListener.